# Update one value depending on other value in SQL

Tags: sql, database

When doing an `INSERT` in SQL, is it possible to do something like this

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES 
('Superman', 100, 
 '[this value will be either 'Good' or 'bad' depending if the previous row is less than or greater than 100]')
```

Comment: What is "*previous*"?

Comment: The last value you insert will be either good or bad, depending on the values that is before it. So the hypothesis is the last value will be either 'Good' or 'Bad' if the one before it meets a specific condition. @PM77-1

Comment: OK. What is "*before*" then?

Comment: I think that the words "previous one" should be changed to be either "previous column/field"  or "previous row".  Though previous row has no real meaning in SQL without an order by which cannot be done in an insert statement.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have edited it properly now

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to do this because it is a parameterized query and you for some reason don't want to compute the "good" or "bad" value externally to the query?  You can make the field '{this value ...' into a case statement

case when $1 > 100
then 'Good'
else 'Bad'
End

where $1 is your parameter.

A computed column may also be what you need if all rows follow the same logic always.  Then you don't need to store 'Good' or 'Bad'.  A view that returns this 'Good' or 'Bad' may also do what you want without handling it on the insert.

Answer (score 1):

you can have conditional in-line value by using for example the `case` statement such as below. here is a MySQL Example:

if your table is defined as follows

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
 column1 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 column2 int(11) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

then the following insert would insert a row with values `'Superman'` and `0`

`insert into testtable (column1,column2) values ('Superman', case when 1>0 then 0 else 100 end);`

you should use some variables to drive the `case` for example:

`insert into testtable (column1,column2) values ('Superman', case when @xcoord > @ycoord then 0 else 100 end);`

lookup more info on `case` to find more customizations.